# Does $\det(A-BC) = \det (A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose that $A$ is $a \times a$, $B$ is $a \times b$ and $C$ is $b \times a$ where $a>b$. Does the following hold?

$$\det(A-BC) = \det (A)$$

I reckon that this is so since $\det(BC) = 0$ because $B$ has more rows than $C$.

Comment: Is "det" a linear function? If not, your last sentence seems suspect.

Comment: @John Hughes, det is determinant of a matrix.

Comment: What John means is that the determinant of the sum/difference is not the sum/difference of the determinants and hence the vanishing of $\det(BC)$ does not imply that only $\det(A)$ remains.

Comment: Take a look at the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma).

Answer (score 4):

Even if $\det BC=0$, it's a mistake to think $\det (A-BC)=\det A -\det BC$.

Comment: I know but is there a way or are there certain conditions when this holds?

Comment: @user556621 The $xy$ cross terms in $\det (x+y)$ make it b unlikely you'll find a condition that vanishes them. Work out the $2\times 2$ case to see what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an explicit counterexample with $a = 2$ and $b = 1$:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad B = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad C = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $$
BC = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \qquad \Rightarrow A - BC = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
 and $\det(A - BC) = 0 \neq \det(A)$.

The flaw in your reasoning is provided by [J.G.'s answer:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2769256/248639) in general, $\det(A + B) \neq \det(A) + \det(B)$.

Comment: I know. But are their conditions to make this true?

Answer (score 0):

One way we can make this happen is by controlling the ranks of the matrices.

We know that $rank(BC) \leq \min(rank(B), rank(C))$ and that $rank(A-BC) \leq rank(A) + rank(BC) \leq rank(A) + \min(rank(B), rank(C))$

So if we keep the ranks of all the matrices small relative to the dimension of $A$, we'll definitely have that $A-BC$ and $A$ are both singular, and consequently $0 = det(A-BC) = det(A)$.

If we don't control the ranks or even allow $A$ to be invertible, 
it might hold under some very special circumstances. As pointed out in the comments, the matrix determinant lemma is where you should look for answers.  For example, one nice case that jumps out at a glance is when $A$ is the identity matrix and $CB = 0$ (which implies $det(BC) =0$ independent of dimension considerations, since $det$ is multiplicative).  In that case the matrix determinant lemma shows $det(A-BC) = 1 = det(A)$.